# How to resize the Intent activity window like a dialog box?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Scenario is when you are clicking a button (Generate Report), it will load a new Intent activity in a full screen.

My requirement is, the activity window should not be in full screen but an automatic width and height*(based on the device large screen and small screen).

Comment: downvoter please comment the what's wrong with the question.?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, you want to show the activity as a dialog.

Then Use `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />` in your manifest for the Activity.

It will look like a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try Activity as a Dialog Box. and you can give the width and height as per you require. the new Activity on button click will emmerge as an Dialog on the current activity.